# Should a public API method return InputStream or byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, api-design, java-http-client

I am designing the API for a client of a service that retrieves data as a stream of bytes.
What is the advantage of using

```
InputStream getData(String param1, String param2);
```

over

```
byte[] getData(String param1, String param2);
```

The method that returns the inputstream bothers me because

1. now my code has to depend on external code to close the inputstream. I know that it is a best practice to close only those resources that you open so this seems wrong.
2. The inputstream is not repeatable. Once the client of my code reads the stream the bytes are lost
3. The stream in my implementation is actually over the network (socket). While I am using a connection pool and monitoring it to get rid of expired connections etc I feel it might be better to be able to close the resources I opened myself.

What's the best way to design this? I even considered using

```
void writeData(String param, String param, OutputStream os);
```

but that makes the method name non-intuitive.

Comment: What is the average size of the data?

Comment: The data is mosty in Kbs  Sometimes in 100s of Kbs and in rare cases it will be some Mb... the data is not really huge..  Mostly text and some times images and rarely video

Comment: Can clients do anything useful with the partial data (as it is being streamed in) or do they need to wait for the entire data?

Comment: No they need to wait for the entire data as it is usually content that needs to be displayed..

Comment: Well, I think byte is better only because you have to close the stream otherwise. If you need the stream for performance reason, I think a method with a "danger" name should be better, maybe getDataUnsafe, dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd return something like Guava's `InputSupplier<InputStream>`, which lets you request multiple distinct input streams.

Additionally, Guava provides a number of methods which take an `InputSupplier<InputStream>`, open an input stream, perform some whole-stream operation, and then close it without making you remember to close the input stream or whatever.

Even if you don't want to use Guava directly, it's a nice technique that lets the client program decide how it wants to deal with it.

Comment: Yes this is a good technique, I could wrap the input stream with a class that remembers to close it when it reaches the end

Comment: InputSupplier is now [deprecated](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html).

Comment: Instead of the deprecated `InputSupplier`, Guava offers [`ByteSource`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html) and [`CharSource`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CharSource.html) since version 14.

Answer (score 7):

byte[] has two possible drawbacks:

- You have to store everything in memory at once - which could be problematic if you are manipulating a lot of data.
- Users of your class will have to wait for all of the data to be available - it is not possible to start processing as soon as some data is available. This can be a significant disadvantage if the network is slow.

Using a Stream can solve those problems. It depends on what data you're returning and what you expect users to do with it.

Comment: I mostly expect users to take it and display it, but we want to build a generic api that is not specific to the current use case

Comment: Have you considered providing two methods ?

Comment: yes... but i would have to name them differently because their return types are different when they actually do the same thing